# Getting GPS data of a remote mobile

Tags: mobile, gps, location

I'm developing a mobile app, somekind of a social networking thing. There I'm planning to intergrate a Location searching facilty to users. Can anyone tell me is it possible to track the gps data of a remote mobile programatically(in j2ME specialy)? I'm preffer to doing this data transfer through GSM or HSDPA. I found `import javax.microedition.location.*;` to get location based data. What I want toknow is, is it possible to get those data of another remote mobile?
Thanks

Comment: Run an app on the other mobile, with the appropriate permissions, and post the GPS coordinates to your servers.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the very quick response. Can't I do this without a server? I mean if the other person has enable his GPS service, can't I find his lat, lon, alt, etc without disturbin him?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Theoretically, you could, but it'd be **vastly** easier to do it with a server. There are many services (like Amazon Web Services) that charge very little. You **do** intend to install an app on the remote mobile, right?

Comment: Yes, the same app will be installed on members' mobiles. App should capable to determine where the otheres(locating on a map and show or something like that)